# How to open database in web browser locally with IBM Notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have Domino Server running locally. I can assess for example the log.nsf and names.nsf databases in the browser (ie. http://localhost/log.nsf).
But I also created my own databases for example test.nsf
when visiting http://localhost/test.nsf, I see this:

```
Error 404
HTTP Web Server: IBM Notes Exception - File does not exist
```

What do I need to do to access views and agents from my own created databases

Comment: Where did you put your "test.nsf" file? If it is in the same directory as names.nsf and log.nsf (of server, I assume you have a client installed as well), then this should work.

Comment: Yes in the same directory + i have the client

Comment: please write the whole directory... I think you created it in the wrong data directory

Comment: log is in c:\program files\IBM\Notes\Data\log.nsf --------

test is in c:\program files\IBM\Notes\Data\test.nsf

Comment: That's what I assumed: This is the data directory of the notes client. Server has to be something like IBM\Domino\Data... You put your application in the wrong directory.

Comment: You need to Create your database "on server" in your client, even when the server is "local" to your client, otherwise it will not work...

Comment: I understand, Is it also possible to just copy and paste the database in the domino folder

Comment: only if it is not locally encrypted

Comment: Create a local replica in the "Notes\Data"- directory is the correct behaviour. You need someone to explain the difference between Domino Server and Notes Client. That is to much for a Platform like this here. You need a training... You need not to create the replica on "local" but on your "Local Domino", this is a big difference.... Sorry, can't help you here.

Comment: Thanks anyway for the help Torsten :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I try to -basically- answer this from the dialog that we had in the comments:

IBM Notes / Domino is a Client- Server solution where **IBM Domino** is the server and **IBM Notes** is the client.

Usually you work with the client and connect to the server that is on another machine.

Notes client is -by default- installed in **C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Notes** and the Data- directory (containing the personal addressbook of the user named names.nsf, the bookmarks and desktop and the client log.nsf) is in **C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Notes\Data** (ignoring multiuser setup on purpose as it makes things to complicated).

A Domino server is -again by default- installed in **C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Domino**, its data directory is in **C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Domino\Data**.

There is a names.nsf and a log.nsf there as well, but names.nsf is the Domino Directory of the server and log.nsf the log of... you guess.

Now one can of course install Notes and Domino on the same machine, but still they are two distinct programs.

To access Databases from a Domino server, you NEVER access them directly via file system but use the Open- Dialog to open them from the server.

If you want to access the files via admin- client (that can be installed along with the Notes Client), then you select "Open Server" from the File- Menu to access it. AGAIN: Don't access server files "directly" although they are on the same machine.

When creating new databases (from client or admin) select the Server to create them, NOT "Local".

What is the problem with the question: You created a database in the Data- directory of the client. The server does NOT know of this database as it has its own Data- directory. it will show the message you wrote.

Create it in the Data- Directory of the server instead then it will work.

Of course one could just copy the database from Notes\Data to Domino\Data. 
But this will -by default- not work either: Out of the box the Notes Client encrypts every local database with the user's ID file. When copied over to Domino the server will not be able to read it. You need to decrypt to database before copy, you can do that in the properties of the database.

All together seems, that you need a training for whatever you try to do, otherwise this question will be your least problem.

Comment: Maybe worth noting... It's technically possible to install Notes and Domino in the same directory, or was with older versions, but it's a bad idea and likely to cause problems. I've seen production servers where someone had done this.

Comment: I thought about writing about the origins (Notes and Domino had been the same for a long time and until Version 5 you could start the client by launching "notes.exe" from Domino directory), but that would have made this already to long post even longer...